# Vue 3 single page app loading empty white screen only on older devices like iphone 6 iphone 6s

Tags: ios, iphone, vue.js, browser, vuetify.js

My vue.js app running on vite is appearing empty white screen with title and favicon but no body on old browsers like safari on iphone 6. I have no clue on how to solve this issue and please if anyone knows how to solve it i am desperate.